# how to get style values with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have a simple html file which consists of a div; and a css file which has a simple styling for the mentioned div:

html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Movement</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #095057;
    background-color: #20979e;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

in my js file i do a simple log as follows:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('square').style.top)
```

but i receive an error:

> ```
>    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
> at index.js:1
> ```

i have no idea why it says style is null.do you?

Comment: So what u want to get in console as result?

Comment: im expecting sth like 200px or 200, so that i could use the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have no idea why it says style is null.do you?

It doesnt.
It says `document.getElementById('square')` returns `null` so youre reading the property `style` on `null` which results in the error.

That happens because your script is loaded (and executed) in the head. At this point the element with the ID "square" isnt existent in the DOM yet.

Move your script to below your element (see snippet) or mark it with `async defer` like this: `<script src="index.js" async defer></script>` to make it load and execute *after* DOM parsing is done.

Also accessing `style` will only show inline styles from the style attribute so that wont get you values from your stylesheet file (or inline stylesheets).

Use `computedStyleMap()` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap) to get the actual computed styles including all stylesheets.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #095057;
  background-color: #20979e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Movement</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="square"></div>
  
  <script>
    console.log(document.getElementById('square').computedStyleMap().get('top').value);
  </script>
</body>



</html>
```